# UPDATE from SELECT query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables. Table `a` uses a ref from table `b`  and I update table `a` with a value from table `b` as such

```
UPDATE
    a
SET
    a.StructureTypeRef = b.StructureTypeRef
FROM
    Template_Structure as a
INNER JOIN
    dbo_StructureType as b
ON
    a.StructureType = b.StructureType
```

Normally I can find `b`'s ref matching the `'structuretype'` field but in this instance I want to insert the `b.StructureTypeRef` where `a.StructureType = 0 and b.StructureType = 'External Areas'`, as the corresponding ref for `'External Areas'` is not 0. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Are there severals rows from the table b with the given criteria ?

Comment: No, there will only be one with the value 'External Areas'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this, its not very clear though what exactly you are asking here

```
UPDATE Template_Structure
SET StructureTypeRef = (SELECT StructureTypeRef
                        FROM dbo_StructureType
                        WHERE StructureType = 'External Areas')
WHERE StructureType = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a
    SET StructureTypeRef = b.StructureTypeRef
FROM Template_Structure a
JOIN StructureTypeRef b ON 1=1 AND b.StructureType = 'External Areas'
WHERE a.StructureType = 0
```

Explanation: `1=1` is useless, however, it is only a way to show there is no "direct" join between both tables. An equivalent request :

```
UPDATE a
    SET StructureTypeRef = b.StructureTypeRef
FROM Template_Structure a
CROSS JOIN StructureTypeRef b
WHERE a.StructureType = 0 and b.StructureType = 'External Areas'
```

Both these requests work because, as the owner answered me, there is a single row in the table b with StructureType = 'External Areas'.